# Flutter Application best place to fetch the data from server

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am building a flutter application where I have to get different kinds of data from the server like different notes that the user has created and the different quizzes that the user has taken . I am confuse where should I fetch that data from the server and display it using a future builder . Right Now what I am doing is I have a welcome page which is the page just after the splash page . I am getting some data in the FutureBuilder and storing that data in a Provider class to show it in a different page for example called the notes page . I dont think this seems like a very good idea . Where Can I fetch the data from the server . Should I do it once and use it over the app or should I do it everytime I go to that specific page for example notes data for the notes page and quiz data for the quiz page etc.

Answer (score 1):

Move GET/POST methods to the `ChangeNotifier` models so they are closer to the model that represents it. This way if an update is made it's easy to fetch the data again in the model itself and notify the listeners.

If the data is static you should fetch it only once in the `initState` (You can store the future in a variable to be used by the `FutureBuilder`). On the other hand, if the data changes just notify the listeners inside the `ChangeNotifier` model.

Supposing `UserModel` is the `ChangeNotifier` model for the user and both `UserModel.fetchNotes` and `UserModel.fetchQuizzes` return a future of notes and a future of quizzes, the code is going to be like the following snippet.

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final Future<List<dynamic>> _futures;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final userModel = context.read<UserModel>();
    // Wait for both fetchNotes and fetchQuizzes
    _futures = Future.wait([
      userModel.fetchNotes(context),
      userModel.fetchQuizzes(context),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _futures,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Error();
        }
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Loading();
        }

        final notes = snapshot.data![0];
        final quizzes = snapshot.data![1];
        ...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the data when the app is first opened.  If you use the [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package, you can keep the splash screen up until your data has finished loading, then use a call to `FlutterNativeSplash.remove();` to remove the splash screen when your data is ready.  In this way, all your data will be available when the app is first displayed to the user.

(Full disclosure - I maintain the flutter_native_splash package)